# Gson is not formatting one variable from json string

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I am trying to convert json format (arraylist response from rest webservice) to corresponding java arraylist.

Surpisingly, only 2 of 3 variables are getting formatted into object and 3 variable is setting into null.

Below is the json response in string format.

```
[{"points":"20","shares":"54","name":"Krishna"},{"points":"18","shares":"47","name":"Bhima"}]
```

I am trying to convert to arraylist with below code:

```
    ArrayList<GplusFriend> gp_list;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gp_list = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<GplusFriend>>(){}.getType());

 Iterator itr = gp_list.iterator();
            GplusFriend gf =null;
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                gf= (GplusFriend) itr.next();
                Log.d("Restcall", "Name :"+gf.getName());
                Log.d("Restcall", "points :"+gf.getPoints());
                Log.d("Restcall", "shares :"+gf.getShares());
                }
```

But I am getting the log as :

```
Name :null
points :20
shares :54
Name :null
points :18
shares :47
```

This is the class definition of GPlusFriend:

```
public class GplusFriend {

    String Name;

    String points;
    String shares;
    public String getShares() {
        return shares;
    }
    public void setShares(String shares) {
        this.shares = shares;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }


    public GplusFriend(){
        super();
    }
    public GplusFriend(String Name,String points,String shares){
        super();

        this.shares=shares;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString(){

        return this.Name + "     "+this.points+"     "+this.shares;

    }
}
```

So what I am missing here..

Comment: Try changing `Name` to `name` in `GPlusFriend` class.

Comment: alternatively, add `@SerializedName("name")` to the `Name` field. That tells GSON to ignore the field name and use whatever you've specified. There's even another approach, see https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
String name;
```

instead of

```
String Name;
```

your JSON key is in small letter "name"
when using GSON, Variable names are case-sensitive

Comment: it is giving..You can accept an answer in 4 minutes. will do once it allows.